# Returning a future that takes reference to a string

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a `Vec` of `Futures` for use with `try_join_all`.

```rust
use futures::future::try_join_all;

struct Image {
    pub file_name: String,
}

struct Storage;

impl Storage {
    async fn upload(&self, filename: &str) -> Result<String, ()> {
        Ok(filename.to_owned())
    }
}

struct ImagesRepository {
    storage: Storage,
}

impl ImagesRepository {
    async fn upload_images(&self, images: &[Image]) -> Result<Vec<String>, ()> {
        let futures = images
            .iter()
            .map(|image| {
                let path_name = format!("somedirectory/{}", &image.file_name);

                let future = self.storage.upload(path_name.as_str());

                future
            })
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();

        let results = try_join_all(futures).await?;

        Ok(results)
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `path_name`
  --> src/lib.rs:30:17
   |
26 |                 let future = self.storage.upload(path_name.as_str());
   |                                                  ------------------ `path_name` is borrowed here
...
30 |                 future
   |                 ^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

This occurs because I'm passing `storage.upload` a reference to `path_name`, which only lives inside the closure.

I know I could change `storage.upload` to take a `String` instead but that means breaking the code for other parts that uses this function.

Is there a way to fix this compiler error?

[Minimal example - Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ddbccf7e0df91d0d71122bcfe818cebd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually rather straightforward.  You just need to wrap the future in another future that owns the string.  You can do this with an `async` block, which is used to create ad-hoc, anonymous `Future`-implementing values (just like `|...|` can be used to create ad-hoc, anonymous `Fn*`-implementing values):

```
.map(|image| async {
    let path_name = format!("somedirectory/{}", &image.file_name);

    self.storage.upload(path_name.as_str()).await
})
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=81e8f6f1257c6ca73f6dbdd118e16ad6))

It is usually an anti-pattern to create a future and return from it the result of awaiting another future, but this is one of the cases when it's not.  That's because the wrapper future doesn't just proxy the inner future's ready value, it also takes care of running `path_name`'s destructor after the inner future becomes ready.

---

If you wanted to, you could even remove the `path_name` variable altogether:

```
.map(|image| async {
    self.storage.upload(
        &format!("somedirectory/{}", &image.file_name)
    ).await
})
```

Comment: Not all people agree this is an antipattern (I personally do), some always wrap futures with `async { ... }`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It's akin to `return await foo();` in JavaScript, which is almost always wrong -- the exception being inside of a `try` block (or a `catch` block when a `finally` block is also present). Although, in Rust, the overhead for this mistake is far less, and possibly even zero if the compiler notices what's going on and inlines one `poll` implementation into the other.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to decouple the steps of creating image url and uploading them, because the former does not need to be an async task, but latter involves a network call and is an async task.

```rust
let upload_urls = images
    .iter()
    .map(|image| format!("somedirectory/{}", &image.file_name))
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();

let futures = upload_urls
    .iter()
    .map(|path_name| self.storage.upload(&path_name))
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();

let results = try_join_all(futures).await?;
```

Comment: The snippet I shared is a simpler version. In reality, `storage.upload` takes in other stuff from `images`, not only `path_name`. That is why iterating through `images` is a requirement in this case. But still, good point.